# Set continuous animation

Tags: javascript, aframe

Is there way to setup continuous animation? Example: based on camera rotation, rotate sphere around it each time camera rotated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component that continuously checks camera rotation and updates sphere using tick:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('rotation-updater', {
  tick: function () {
    var sphere = this.el;
    var camera = this.el.sceneEl.cameraEl;

    var cameraRotation = camera.getAttribute('rotation');
    // var sphereRotation = DO SOMETHING WITH CAMERA ROTATION.
    sphere.setAttribute('rotation', sphereRotation);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Kevin! Why not creating new AFRAME.TWEEN.Tween().blabla().start() and using .update() in tick ?

Comment: OP wanted it conditional based on the camera rotation. Tween can only do basic interpolations.

Comment: But if I want to use easing as well, I can not simply do such workaround :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe Tween will work, but you'd have to redefine the animation often. Try it out.

Alternatively, you could do math to get the easing you desire in the component. It'll be a bit involved. `tick` will provide global time and delta time, you periodically set a new target rotation, get a percentage of how far you are into the easing, and use an easing function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can be used when animation should be finite:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('camera-seeker', {
    init() {
        this.CAMERA = document.querySelector('#player');
        this.newCords = {};
        this.setupAnimation();
    },

    setupAnimation () {
        let el = this.el;
        var this_ = this;
        seekAnim = new AFRAME.TWEEN.Tween(this.el.getAttribute('rotation'))
            .to(this.newCords, 30000)
            .easing(AFRAME.TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out)
            .onUpdate(function () {
                el.setAttribute('rotation', `${this.x}, ${this.y}, ${this.z}`);
            })
            .repeat(Infinity)
            .start();
    },

    tick () {
        if (!isGameStart()) return;
        if (AFRAME.utils.coordinates.stringify(this.CAMERA.getAttribute('rotation')) !== AFRAME.utils.coordinates.stringify(this.el.getAttribute('rotation'))) {
            Object.assign(this.newCords, this.CAMERA.getAttribute('rotation'));
        }
    }
});
```